# How do I make JQuery-isotope work with an element that changes height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

Suppose I have many elements, and isotope works perfectly.

Now, when a user click "show image" on one of the links inside an element, the element shows an image. The problem is...isotope doesn't automatically take this into account, and the image "overlaps" with the element underneath it.

How do I fix this?

I would like the bottom element to automatically move down, to make room for the expanded top element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `reLayout` on your container after the item changes size.

```
$('#myContainer').isotope('reLayout');
```

Comment: thanks! Do you know how I can disable the animation , when doing reLayout?

Comment: Set the animationEngine option to 'none': http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/options.html#animationengine

Comment: when I call "reLayout", the rows move left and right. Is there any way I can just slide the bottom row down instead of having everything move left/right across the screen? (I'm using the "masonry" layout...should I use another layout method?) thanks

Comment: Unfortunately any of the "packing" layout types are going to attempt to fit everything as tightly as possible, so it won't be possible to achieve what you're describing purely in Masonry. (see example: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/relayout.html)

Comment: Thanks. What would be the best solution to do it? (Pinterest doesn't move stuff left and right...it just pushes the bottom down)

Comment: Without seeing your code it's difficult to know, but all Masonry is doing is calculating absolute positions for each cell. You could look for items whose `left` is in the range of `targetItem.left` to `targetItem.left+targetItem.width` and move all of their `top` += `targetItem.newHeight - targetItem.oldHeight`.